# Is it possible in igGrid Infragistics 2012 control insert carriage return and/or line feed?

Tags: javascript, infragistics, carriage-return, ignite-ui, iggrid

Is it possible in igGrid Infragistics control insert

> carriage return / line feed

inside the text of a cell?

For example given the next datasource:

```
var ds = [
        { "Id": 1, "Name": "Adjustable \\r\\n Race", "ProductNumber": "AR-5381", "soldi" : 10.10 },
        { "Id": 2, "Name": "Bearing Ball", "ProductNumber": "BA-8327", "soldi" : 20.10  },
        { "Id": 3, "Name": "BB Ball Bearing", "ProductNumber": "BE-2349", "soldi" : 30.10  }
    ];
```

you can see between the words Adjustable and Race the chars "\r\n", but it doesn't work... I tried:

```
"\r", "\r\n", "\line", "<br />", "&#13;"
```

in every test I see on screen the chars and not the new line... maybe there is a setting I don't know...

If you need a complete test example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Infragistics Combined CSS -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link href="Scripts/jqueryUI/css/humanity/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="./Scripts/InfragisticsNetAdvantage2012.1/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="./Scripts/InfragisticsNetAdvantage2012.1/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />        

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jqueryUI/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.ba-outside-events.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/InfragisticsNetAdvantage2012.1/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/InfragisticsNetAdvantage2012.1/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/InfragisticsNetAdvantage2012.1/Common/jQuery/Common/js/infragistics.loader.js"></script>

    <script src="./Scripts/InfragisticsNetAdvantage2012.1/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
    <script src="./Scripts/InfragisticsNetAdvantage2012.1/Common/jQuery/Common/js/infragistics.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   var ds = [
        { "Id": 1, "Name": "Adjustable \\r\\n Race", "ProductNumber": "AR-5381", "soldi" : 10.10 },
        { "Id": 2, "Name": "Bearing Ball", "ProductNumber": "BA-8327", "soldi" : 20.10  },
        { "Id": 3, "Name": "BB Ball Bearing", "ProductNumber": "BE-2349", "soldi" : 30.10  },
        { "Id": 4, "Name": "Headset Ball Bearings", "ProductNumber": "BE-2908", "soldi" : 40.10  },
        { "Id": 316, "Name": "Blade", "ProductNumber": "BL-2036", "soldi" : 50.10  },
        { "Id": 317, "Name": "LL Crankarm", "ProductNumber": "CA-5965", "soldi" : 60.10  },
        { "Id": 318, "Name": "ML Crankarm", "ProductNumber": "CA-6738", "soldi" : 70.10  },
        { "Id": 319, "Name": "HL Crankarm", "ProductNumber": "CA-7457", "soldi" : 80.10  },
        { "Id": 320, "Name": "Chainring Bolts", "ProductNumber": "CB-2903", "soldi" : 10.10 }
    ];

    $(function () {

        $("#gridUpdating").igGrid({
            primaryKey: "Id",
            renderCheckboxes: true,
            columns: [
                { headerText: "Make Flag", key: "MakeFlag", dataType: "bool",  readOnly: false, width: "200"},
                { headerText: "Product ID", key: "Id", dataType: "number", width: "200"  },
                { headerText: "Product Name", key: "Name", dataType: "string", width: "200" },
                { headerText: "Product Number", key: "ProductNumber", dataType: "string" , width: "200" },
                { headerText: "soldi", key: "soldi", dataType: "number" , width: "200", format: "##.##,##" }
            ],

            dataSourceType: "json",

            dataSource: ds,

            headerRendered: function(evt, ui) {
                console.log($($('#gridUpdating').igGrid("headersTable")).html());
            },

            rowsRendered: function(evt, ui) {
                $.each(ui.owner.element.find("tr td:nth-child(5)"), function() {
                    var row = $(this).closest('tr')
                    rowId = $(row).attr("data-id");
                    if(rowId){
                        $(this).html((parseFloat($(this).html(),10).toFixed(2)).toString().replace(".",","));
                    }
                });

                $.each(ui.owner.element.find("tr td:nth-child(1)"), function() {
                    var row = $(this).closest('tr')
                    rowId = $(row).attr("data-id");
                    if(rowId){
                        $(this).html("<input type='checkbox' name='chk' id='chk_" + rowId + "' />");
                    }
                });

                $(ui.owner.element.find("tr td:nth-child(1)")).bind('click', function(){

                    var row = $(this).closest('tr')
                    rowId = $(row).attr("data-id");

                })
            },

            features: [
            {
                name: "Updating",
                enableAddRow: true,
                editMode: "none",
                enableDeleteRow: false,
                rowDeleting: function (e, args) 
                { 
                    alert(1);
                },
                rowDeleted: function (e, args){ 
                    alert(2);
                },
                columnSettings: [
                    { columnKey: "MakeFlag", editorOptions: { type: "bool", readOnly: false, disabled: false} },
                    { columnKey: "Id", editorOptions: { type: "numeric", readOnly: true, disabled: true} },
                    { columnKey: "Name", editorOptions: { type: "bool", readOnly: true, disabled: true} },
                    { columnKey: "ProductNumber", editorOptions: { type: "bool", readOnly: true, disabled: true} }
                ]
            }]
        });


    });
    function bind(){
        $("#gridUpdating").igGrid("option", "dataSource", ds);
        $("#gridUpdating").igGrid("dataBind");
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="gridUpdating"></table>
    <input type="button" value="BIND" onclick="bind();" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found after a while that my problem was in the proxy service which I use to consume my server code, it html-encoded every special character, for example for "< b r / >" I was receiving "& l t ; b r  / & g t ;", so I had only to replace it with "< b r / >" before binding...